realizar un programa para llenar datos de ua matrix de orden n*n con los n primeros valores de la aserie fibonacci en el orden de ejemplo indicado
Realizar un programa para llenar datos de ua matrix de orden n*n con los n primeros valores de la aserie fibonacci en el orden de jemplo indicado en la tabla 1. mediante metodos personalizaos llenar la matriz A utilizando recursividad llenar la matriz b con los valores obtenidos de la suma de digitos pares de cada elemento almacenado en la matriz A. Imprimir los valores de las matrices A y B.
Grupo 2:
2                3                 21                   34,
144               1                 5                    13,
233              89                 1                    8,
610              367               55                    0
tengo este codigo que si me llena correctamente la serie fibonacci pero no empieza desde la ultima fila ultima columna
// Método recursivo para calcular el n-ésimo valor de la serie Fibonacci

public static int fibonacci(int n) {
    if (n <= 1) {
        return n;
    }
    return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
}

// Método recursivo para llenar la matriz con los valores de la serie Fibonacci
public static void llenarMatriz(int[][] matriz, int n, int fila, int columna) {
    if (fila == n) {
        return;
    }
    if (columna == n) {
        llenarMatriz(matriz, n, fila + 1, 0);
        return;
    }
    matriz[fila][columna] = fibonacci(fila * n + columna);
    llenarMatriz(matriz, n, fila, columna + 1);
}

// Método para imprimir la matriz
public static void imprimirMatriz(int[][] matriz) {
    for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(matriz[i][j] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

